# CentOS, Debian or Fedora for an Ubuntu User?

Tags: ubuntu, debian, centos, fedora

I've got the choice of these three systems for a VPS package I think I'm going to go with. My main experience is with Ubuntu so what do you recommend to go with?

The VPS will basically be used for hosting PHP/WordPress and MySQL.

Comment: Shopping Questions and product recommendations are Off-Topic on any of the [se] sites. See [Q and A is hard, lets go Shopping](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping) and the [FAQ] for more details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you know Ubuntu, Debian will be by far the most familiar. There is very little difference between Ubuntu and Debian on a server. CentOS and Fedora will require you to learn how to use RPM and will have files in a different place. For example, they do not have /etc/network/interfaces and Apache configuration is in /etc/httpd. They're just two I can think of off the top of my head.

Comment: Thanks David and Adrien. Debian also has the most "tagged" articles on serverfault.com at the moment so I imagine this is one of the most popular (hopefully not the most broken).

Comment: There's a reason why Ubuntu picked Debian as a base :) Lenny should be rock solid. Probably more so than any other distribution.

Comment: Personally I'm a Fedora user, but I agree with this answer: if you have experience with Ubuntu, Debian is your best bet.

Answer (score 1):

IIRC, Ubuntu is a Debian derivative, so maybe Debian?

Comment: It is based on Debian - so, in this case then go for what you're used to

Answer (score 0):

ubuntu is a debian-based distro, while centos and fedora are children of the now defunct redhat distro

speaking from package manager point of view, debian+ubuntu use apt-get/dpkg, while centos+fedora use rpm

while all four of them are system v init style, some apps will store their files/config files on different places, dependig on the chosen distro

so you should use whichever is easier for you to run and maintain

Comment: Actually, CentOS is line for line the same source as RHEL, with only the trademarks and RHEL branding removed.

Comment: Fedora is upstream of RHEL and CentOS is downstream of RHEL. RHEL is certainly not "defunct".