# Going from Ubuntu server to Debian server

Tags: ubuntu, debian

I am well pretty well versed in Ubuntu server management.  I have been thinking of switching to Debian.  Obviously ubuntu is a debian fork, but is it pretty much the same feel as ubuntu?  Will I feel at home when working in cli, or will I need some time to catch on and feel comfortable?  I know the best way will be to just set debian up, and try it out, but I would like opinions first before I dedicate myself to this.

Specifically going from Ubuntu 10.04/11.10 to debian 6.

Comment: Just want to throw in a plug for CentOS. Debian stable is, well, stable, but some of the packages are exceedingly old versions. CentOS is a nice mix of stability and new features, but there will be a minor learning curve moving from Ubuntu/Debian.

Comment: I came from Centos a few years ago.  I actually like ubuntu a lot better than centos, and I am pretty sure I will like debian better than ubuntu.  Centos felt a lot sloppier than ubuntu.  Less headaches.

Answer (score 2):

You should feel perfectly at home. The only noticeable difference would be Upstart and slower release cycles.

I've been a long time Debian server person; and found no real caveats to doing anything between the two.

See: [CentOS, Debian or Fedora for an Ubuntu User?](https://serverfault.com/questions/60260/centos-debian-or-fedora-for-an-ubuntu-user)

and: [how different are ubuntu and debian (generally) for servers?](https://serverfault.com/questions/89816/how-different-are-ubuntu-and-debian-generally-for-servers)

Comment: I have done a lot of research on the release cycles and lts of debian.  My concern is mostly with the general workflow and day to day tasks between the two, and how "at home" I would feel.  But thanks, I am going to spin up a debian box tomorrow and have some fun.

Comment: Like I said, you'll feel perfectly at home :)